# working with bc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, bc

trying to sum elements in an array using bc,i have a file with names and thier vaules if the names appears 3 times i should multiply its value with 3 then find the sum of all the elements together,im seeing standard input error

```
$ cat foo.txt

max 2.3 
henry 3
fransis 4.5
max 2.3
henry 3
max 2.3
```

it should show on the terminal

```
max 6.9
henry 6 
fransis 4.5
```

then

```
total 17.9
```

```
declare -A array

while read name value; do

     array[$name]=$( echo "${array[$name]:-0} + $value" | bc )

done < cat foo.txt

for name in "${!array[@]}"; do

     echo "$name ${array[$name]}"

done
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with just the shell and `bc` instead of using something like `awk`?

Comment: Why use `bc`? `$(echo 1+1 | bc)` can be replaced by `$((1+1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're required to use `bc` but this could be done with the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{names[$1]=$1;vals[$1]+=$2} END {for(i in names){sum+=vals[i];print i, vals[i]}; print "total " sum}' foo.txt
```

Comment: i was trying to see how bc can do it

Comment: dude i was trying your code and it worked perfectly is it ok for you to explain the code im new to awk i would like to know whats going on in this code you wrote for me

Comment: The first part tells awk what to do for each record in the file: {names[$1]=$1;vals[$1]+=$2}. This will store the values of the first column ($1) in an array called names[]. It also keeps a running sum of the second column ($2) for each name in the first column in the array vals[].

Comment: The second part tells awk what to do after processing all the lines: END {for(i in names){sum+=vals[i];print i, vals[i]}; print "total " sum}. This will loop through the items in names[] and use each name as an index into the vals[] array. Tallying up the total sum into a variable called sum, as well as printing the name (print i) and printing the indivual sums (print vals[i]). Finally it will print the total sum (print "total " sum). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In true bash spirit, here's a series of piped commands to achieve this :)

```
echo 'max 2.3
henry 3
fransis 4.5
max 2.3
henry 3
max 2.3' | \
sort | \
uniq -c | \
while read count name value
  do echo "$name" $(bc <<< "$count * $value")
done | \
sort -r -k 2
```

---

`sort | uniq -c` will count the number of identical lines and produce a list like this:

```
1 fransis 4.5
2 henry 3
3 max 2.3
```

This list is passed to a `while` loop that reads 3 values at a time (`read count name value`)

For each set of 3 values, it prints the name and the multiplication result:

```
echo "$name" $(bc <<< "$count * $value")
```

The result is then sorted so that the highest score is at the top, i.e. reverse sort on the second column:

```
sort -r -k 2
```

---

This all assumes that the input file is "well formed", with no malformed lines or extra whitespace.

Comment: I would replace the xargs component with `while read c name v; do echo "$n $((c * v))"; done`.

Comment: @Mark: bash won't support floating point math :(  but yeah, a while loop is much better!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `cat` from the `done < cat foo.txt` line.

**Update:** Reomove any empty lines from the input file, too.